# || and && with CSS selectors

Tags: selenium, xpath, css-selectors

I need to find out the CSS selector where

> div class="ui-widget-content slick-row even" OR div class="ui-widget-content     slick-row odd"

How can I write a CSS selector for this. Tried out:

> div([class^='ui-widget-content slick-row']:div([class$='even'],div([class$='odd'].

Comment: Could you not just use an XPath? All you're really doing is checking for the presence of a classname, and XPath is good at handling conditions

Comment: @Ben- I have similar class names in the same page. Also I have posted only the portion of the CSS that requires AND OR.So cannot just check the presence of class name.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work :

```
div.ui-widget-content.slick-row.even,div.ui-widget-content.slick-row.odd
```